# Newsletter php (email com campos vazios)

Tags: php, newsletter

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Eu vi isto na net e tentei aproveitar, no entanto no meu email recebo os campos "Nome:" e "Email:" mas estão completamente vazios, mas ao enviar eu envio com os campos preenchidos!

index.html

```
<form method="POST" action="newsletter.php">
                        <li>
                            <input type="text" class="text" value="Nome">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="text" class="text" value="Email">
                        </li>
                            <input type="submit" value="submit">
                    </form>
```

newsletter.php

```
# RESULT PAGE
$location = "";

## FORM VALUES ##

# SENDER - WE ALSO USE THE RECIPIENT AS SENDER
# DON'T INCLUDE UNFILTERED USER INPUT IN THE MAIL HEADER!
# SEE ALSO: How to protect a php Email Form using php mail or mb_send_mail against Mail Header Injection
$sender = $recipient;

# MAIL BODY
$body = "Name: ".$_REQUEST['Nome']." \n";
$body = "Email: ".$_REQUEST['Email']." \n";
# add more fields here if required

## SEND MESSGAE ##

mail($subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("O email não pode ser enviado.");

## SHOW RESULT PAGE ##

header( "Location: $location" );
?>
```

Obrigado

Comment: Já alterei, o javascript fazia parte de uma outra abordagem, nada a haver :)

Comment: Se o método for sempre POST acho melhor trocar o $_REQUEST por $_POST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Falta o atributo *name* nos seus inputs.

```
<input type="text" class="text" value="Nome" name="Nome">
<input type="text" class="text" value="Email" name="Email">
```

Sem falar no php que você substitui o conteúdo de `$body` na segunda vez que você atribui valor a ele. O certo seria algo assim:

```
$body = "Name: ".$_REQUEST['Nome']." \n";
$body .= "Email: ".$_REQUEST['Email']." \n";
```

Comment: Resolveu! Obrigado!

Comment: De nada, sempre que posso ajudo^^